# Automount USB sticks on Gentoo

Tags: gentoo, usb-drive

I have a bare-bone Genoo installed with two user and a guest account enabled. I want to auto-mount the usb sticks whenever they are plugged in for all accounts with user read-write permission.

What is the best way to do it? I am superuser on this system and can install or modify system files. I am looking for a easy solution i.e. I should be able to do it without modifying many files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a good [Gentoo HOWTO Fully Automated USB mounting using udev](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-350769-highlight-udev.html)
another way - to add into udev rules some rule(s) like described [here](https://github.com/HalisCz/udev-automount/blob/master/10-flash-mounts.rules)

in general, you have to create file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` (let's name it as "10-flash-mounts.rules") with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh  
# start at sdb to ignore the system hard drive  
KERNEL!="sd[b-z]*", GOTO="exit"  
ACTION=="add", PROGRAM!="/sbin/blkid %N", GOTO="exit"  

# import some useful filesystem info as variables  
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"  

# get the label if present, otherwise assign one based on device/partition  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="flash_drive_%k"  

# create the dir in /media and symlink it to /mnt  
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p '/media/%E{dir_name}'"  

# global mount options  
#ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"  

# filesystem-specific mount options (777/666 dir/file perms for vfat) 
ACTION=="add",ENV{mount_options_vfat}="gid=100,dmask=000,fmask=111,utf8,flush,rw,noatime,users"

# add device to /etc/fstab  
#ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat", RUN+="/bin/sed -i '$a\/dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name} vfat %E{mount_options_vfat} 0 0' /etc/fstab"  

# mount device  
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat", RUN+="/bin/mount -t auto -o %E{mount_options_vfat} /dev/%k '/media/%E{dir_name}'"  

# clean up after device removal  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l '/media/%E{dir_name}'", RUN+="/bin/rmdir '/media/%E{dir_name}'"  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}!="", RUN+="/bin/sed -i '/\/dev\/%k /d' /etc/fstab"  

# exit  
LABEL="exit"
```